# Can we limit or customize response data from contentful to reduce network traffic

Tags: node.js, contentful

Is there a way that we can limit response data coming from the contentful.

I did search on documentation but didn't fine anything on this. https://www.contentful.com/developers/docs/references/content-management-api/

Also i am using this node module
https://www.npmjs.com/package/contentful-management

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently there are only two possible ways of limiting the data returned by Contentful:

1. Use the `limit` parameter to reduce the amount of resources. The default value here is 100. ([see docs](https://www.contentful.com/developers/docs/references/content-delivery-api/#/reference/search-parameters/limit))
2. Use the `include=0` parameter to avoid including of linked items. The default value here is including one level of included items. ([see docs](https://www.contentful.com/developers/docs/references/content-delivery-api/#/reference/links/omission-of-linked-items))

Comment: Thanks for your reply.. I am looking for reducing fields in the entry response. It returns me entire data. i would like to customize/select the keys that it response should return.

Comment: I understood your question in the first place but this is not possible currently.